# Why does this inverse work

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$U_n$ is defined to be a set such that $ \{\ [a] \in \mathbb{Z_n} \mid \gcd(a,n)=1 \}\ $ where $ \{\ [0] \}\ $ is obviously omitted.

I'm proving that $(U_n , \cdot_n)$ is a group and I have come to the inverse part.

So I have noticed that $a^2 = 1, \ \ \ \forall \ [a] \in G$

The tricky part is proving this. Now I am not required to bring the most convoluted and rigorous proof in the world but a solid simple proof would be great.

I also realize that I may be wrong and that $a^2$ for any $a$ is not an inverse function in $G$. If that is the case, please throw me on the right track.

Comment: What are $U_n$ and $*_n$?

Comment: If a group has the property $a^2=1$ for all $a$, then you should be able to show that $a$ is the inverse of $a$.

Comment: $U_n$ is defined to be a set such that $ \{\ [a] \in \mathbb{Z_n} \mid \gcd(a,n)=1 \}\ $ where $ \{\ [0] \}\ $ is obviously omitted.

$*_n$ is supposed to read $ \cdot_n$, sorry

Comment: It is not true that $a^2 = 1$ for all $a$.  For example $2^2 = 4$ in $\mathbb Z_5$.

Comment: Then the proof is not entirely elementary... If $\gcd(a,n) = 1$, you can write a Bézout identity $au+nv = 1$, then the inverse of $a$ is $u$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that or should I go read up on this Bezout identity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not true that $[a]^2 = [1]$ for all $[a]$ in all $\mathbb Z_n$.  For example $[2]^2 = [4]$ in $\mathbb Z_5$.

**Hint:** Let $[a] \in \mathbb Z_n$ with $(a, n) = 1$.  Did you know that if $(a, n) = 1$ then there exist integers $x, y$ such that $ax + ny = 1$?  What happens when you reduce that equation modulo $n$?

Comment: I'm not sure how to reduce an equation by a modulo. But I'm guessing that the $ny$ part gets omitted or something similar?

Comment: The set $\mathbb Z_n$ should be a set of equivalence classes with the $+$ and $\cdot$ operations on $\mathbb Z_n$ are given by $[a] + [b] = [a + b]$ and $[a]\cdot[b] = [ab]$.  Any equation that holds for integers will hold for the equivalence classes in $\mathbb Z_n$ that these integers represent.  "Reducing mod $n$" just means replacing each integer with the equivalence class in $\mathbb Z_n$ that it represents.

Comment: This answer (correctly) guides towards the fact that every element in the Units modulo $n$ has a multiplicative inverse.  But, it does not address the OP's question about every element being its own inverse.  If you copy your comment from above into this answer, the answer will be *really* good. :)

Comment: @anorton: Done :)

Comment: @Jim :) +1${}{}$

Comment: Do you mean $\gcd(a,n)$ in your answer?

Comment: Also, sorry for being obtuse but I'm not understanding this fully.

My problem is what happens when I reduce by mod $n$. ax+ny=1..

Comment: I'm getting $ax=1 $ ?

Comment: @Paze Correct, $\,{\rm mod}\ \color{#c00}n\!:\ \color{#c00}{n\equiv 0},\,$ so $\,1\equiv ax+\color{#c00}ny\equiv ax+\color{#c00}0y\equiv ax. \ \ $

Comment: @Paze It is a (somewhat) common abbreviation to use $(x, y)$ for $\gcd(x, y)$.

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't know [Bezout's Identity,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) you can instead use [little Fermat.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) Suppose $\,\gcd(a,n)=1.\,$ To show that $\,a\,$ is invertible mod $\,n\,$ it suffices to show the same for every prime factor $p$ of $a$, since products of invertibles are invertible. Since $\,p\nmid n,\,$ by [little Fermat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) $\,n^{p-1} \equiv 1\pmod p,\,$ so $\,n^{p-1}\! + k\,p = 1\,$ for some integer $\,k.\,$ Thus $\,kp\equiv 1\pmod n.\ \ $ **QED**